# How to delete a key and its values from a dictionary based on its position Python

Tags: python, dictionary

From what I have read, dictionaries are 'unordered' so finding a key and its values based on position is not possible. Is there another way to do this and return the same dictionary without the key and the key's values based on the position selected.
I want to set a variable to the position of the key so the user can select which key to delete along with that keys values (can be double ups of key names and values).  The keys and values in this dictionary are strings, not integers and change everytime I run the script as the two strings I combine differ based on user input.

example to work off:
receipt = {'beef': 'mint', 'beef':'chips', 'chicken':'chips'}

Comment: If you know dicts are unordered, why are you trying to delete based on index? There's also `collections.OrderedDict` but I think this is an XY problem. You also can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: `{'beef': 'mint', 'beef':'chips', 'chicken':'chips'}` isn't a dictionary as beef comes twice, so it will override the beefs value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to remove a key by position

There is not a direct API for indexing dictionaries, but you can list the keys, select a key by position and then remove it from the dictionary.

```
def remove_key(d, i):
    'Mutate the dictionary to remove i-th key'
    keys = d.keys()
    del d[keys[i]]
    return d
```

### Specific case for "double-ups"

If you data is doubled-up, a dictionary will eliminate the duplicates before you can get to the pairs.  So, the data needs to be stored as a list of key/value pairs rather than as a dictionary.  That will also allow you to directly delete by position:

```
>>> receipt = [('beef', 'mint'), ('beef', 'chips'), ('chicken', 'chips')]
>>> del receipt[1]
>>> receipt
[('beef', 'mint'), ('chicken', 'chips')]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, sort the keys and use index of the key in that list to delete the key,value from the dict. See the below case. Improvise to use in your program.

```
mydict = {'c':'qwe','a':'asd','b':'acb'}
for key in sorted(mydict.keys()):
    print(key,":",mydict[key])
```

This will print-

```
a:asd
b:acb
c:qwe
```

Answer (score -1):

What you think is a dictionary: `receipt = {'beef': 'mint', 'beef':'chips', 'chicken':'chips'}` is not a dictionary, as dictionaries cannot have multiple values with the same key.

And as dicts cannot have multiple values with the same key, it doesn't make sense to remove values based on position.